# In 2 Corinthians 6:7 what are the weapons of righteousness in the right hand and in the left?

Tags: 2-corinthians, pauline-epistles, niv

2 Corinthians 6:7 NIV

7 in truthful speech and in the power of God; with ***weapons of righteousness in the right hand and in the left***

What are these weapons of righteousness in the right hand and in the left?

Answer (score 2):

**In 2 Corinthians 6:7 what are the weapons of righteousness in the right hand and in the left?**

2 Corinthians 6:7 NIV

> 7 in truthful speech and in the power of God; with weapons of
> righteousness in the right hand and in the left

A soldier usually held his sword, a weapon of attack, in his right hand and carried his shield, for his defense, in his left. Paul used these weapons of righteousness, including God’s word, to advance the cause of truth and to defend pure worship from attack.
Paul and his associates were fully armed to wage spiritual warfare, the “weapons” Paul used were righteous or just means for furthering the cause of true worship against all assaults. (2 Cor.  10:4- 5; Eph 6:16- 17; Heb 4:12)

2 Corinthians 10:4-5 NASB

> 4 for the weapons of our warfare are not of the flesh, but [a]divinely
> powerful for the destruction of fortresses.5 We are destroying
> arguments and all arrogance raised against the knowledge of God, and
> we are taking every thought captive to the obedience of Christ,

Ephesians 6:16-17 NASB

> 16 [a]in addition to all, taking up the shield of faith with which you
> will be able to extinguish all the flaming arrows of the evil one. 17
> And take the helmet of salvation and the sword of the Spirit, which is
> the word of God.

Hebrews 4:12 NASB

> 12 For the word of God is living and active, and sharper than any
> two-edged sword, even penetrating as far as the division of soul and
> spirit, of both joints and marrow, and able to [a]judge the thoughts
> and intentions of the heart.